# My Unittest assertion error comparing pandas dataframe doesn't make sense to me

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, unit-testing

Hopefully a quickie.

My unit test asks:

```
self.assertIsInstance(pd.DataFrame, type(filedata))
```

filedata is definitely a dataframe but I still get the following error.

> AssertionError: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> is not an instance of <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Any pointers welcomed as I've used this exact form elsewhere in this unit test module and it is not an issue.

Comment: what happens if you try without the `type()` around `filedata`?

Comment: We can't reproduce your problem without your code.

Comment: There is no need to give more than what he is showing, the problem is  that he is passing a `type` instead of the object itself. @nicomp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` is not needed - the function does it for you already.

And in a side note, you should replace the sides of your parameters (just for good practice - left is the examine object, and right is the class)

```
self.assertIsInstance(filedata, pd.DataFrame)
```